# html5 canvas - Image data empty after drawing an emoji with large font size on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, html5-canvas

I am drawing an emoji on a `<canvas>` element using the `fillText` method of the 2D context, and right after I am using `getImageData` to get the image as an array, like so :

```
ctx.fillText('', 500, 500)
const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 1000, 1000)
```

This works without any issue on firefox and iOS, but for some reason, `imageData` comes out empty on Chrome (Chromium 75.0.3770.90) when the font size is too big. See the following snippet :

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OKWMBb?editors=1111

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>
    <canvas id="c1" width="1000px" height="1000px"></canvas>
    <canvas id="c2" width="1000px" height="1000px"></canvas>
    <canvas id="c3" width="1000px" height="1000px"></canvas>
    <script>
        var c1 = document.querySelector('#c1')
        var c2 = document.querySelector('#c2')
        var c3 = document.querySelector('#c3')
        var ctx1 = c1.getContext('2d')
        var ctx2 = c2.getContext('2d')
        var ctx3 = c3.getContext('2d')

        ctx1.font = '500px monospace'
        ctx2.font = '500px monospace'
        ctx3.font = '200px monospace'

        ctx1.fillText('', 500, 500)
        ctx2.fillText('', 500, 500)
        ctx3.fillText('', 500, 500)

        function printImageData(ctx, canvasId) {
            const imageData1 = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 1000, 1000)
            console.log(`${canvasId} has data : `, !imageData1.data.every((v) => v === 0))
        }

        setTimeout(() => printImageData(ctx1, '#c1'), 100)
        printImageData(ctx2, '#c2')
        printImageData(ctx3, '#c3')

        // Chrome prints :
        // #c2 has data :  false
        // #c3 has data :  true
        // #c1 has data :  true

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I suspect this has to do with rendering time for the big emoji, but I can't find any reference of this anywhere, nor any workaround (besides the not-very robust `setTimeout` hack).

Answer (score 1):

That's indeed a weird bug, very probably in `getImageData`, `drawImage` is not affected.
So one trick to workaround that issue is to call `ctx.drawImage(ctx.canvas, 0,0);` before getting the image data:

```js
var c1 = document.querySelector('#c1');
var c2 = document.querySelector('#c2');
var ctx1 = c1.getContext('2d');
var ctx2 = c2.getContext('2d');

ctx1.font = '500px monospace';
ctx2.font = '500px monospace';

ctx1.fillText('', 500, 500);
ctx2.fillText('', 500, 500);

function printImageData(ctx, canvasId) {
  const imageData1 = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
  console.log(`${canvasId} has data : `, !imageData1.data.every((v) => v === 0));
}

// #c1 has no workaround applied
printImageData(ctx1, '#c1');
// #c2 has the workaround applied
ctx2.globalCompositeOperation = "copy";
ctx2.drawImage(ctx2.canvas, 0, 0);
ctx2.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
printImageData(ctx2, '#c2');
```

```html
<canvas id="c1" width="1000px" height="1000px"></canvas>
<canvas id="c2" width="1000px" height="1000px"></canvas>
```

---

*After further tests, it seems the problem is that these emojis can't be drawn by software only when the font-size is bigger than `256px` (at least when I disable Hardware acceleration, they're just not rendered at all). Thus I guess *getImageData* is somehow forcing software rendering, and making it fail even when HW acceleration is turned on.

I opened [this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=988331) on chromium's bug-tracker, but note that your particular case with HWA on is actually already fixed in canary version 78.*

Comment: thanks for filing a bug report :) your fix seems to do the trick! Can you explain a bit why that works? Setting `globalCompositeOperation` + copying the canvas onto itself  ?

Comment: globalCompositeOperation="copy" here is just to be sure we don't change the image, for instance if there was some semi opaque pixels, they'd be drawn against themselves in source-over and hence more opaque. For why drawImage works, my gut says that it might ensure the fillText is performed by the GPU, and getImageData will correctly wait after this operation succeeded, while apparently it was forcing fillText to use software rendering. But that's still guess, maybe someone will give some light on the crbug. But note that it will still fail for users without HW acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATE

After some more test it seams there is a problem

This is not expected behavior and is a **BUG** with Chromes rendering.

The rest is the original answer before I found that bug with updates marked.

### Alignment?

I dont see any problem Chrome 75.0.3770.142

However it could be that the font is just offset and thus missing the canvas.

Make sure you have set the text alignments as your example is just on the canvas on the right side.

```
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
```

### Scale via transform

If this still does not work you can scale the font using the 2D transform

#### Example

```
// set constants
const fontSize = 500;            // Size you want
const usingFontSize = 100;       // size of font you are using
const scaleFontBy = fontSize / usingFontSize;  // calculates scale 
const [x, y] = [500, 500];       // where to draw text

// set 2D state
ctx.font = usingFontSize + "px monospace" 
ctx.textAlign = "center";        // ensure rendering is centered
ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
ctx.setTransform(scaleFontBy, 0, 0, scaleFontBy, x, y);

// render content
ctx.fillText('', 0, 0);      // Draw at center of transformed space

// Restore transform state to default
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
```

### Updated Demo

*Update* Will log error when can not get pixel of rendered font.

To test it out the following example draws font 50 to 2500pixels (or more if you want).

```js
requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var w,h, x, y;
const usingFontSize = 64;       // size of font you are using
const fontSizeMax = 2500;         // Max Size you want
const fontSizeMin = 50;           // Min Size you want
const text = ",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,".split(",");
function draw(text,fontSize) {
    if (innerHeight !== canvas.height) {
        // resize clears state so must set font and alignment
        h = canvas.height = innerHeight;
        w = canvas.width = innerWidth;
        ctx.font = usingFontSize + "px monospace" 
        ctx.textAlign = "center";        // ensure rendering is centered
        ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        ctx.lineJoin = "round";
        ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
        x = w / 2;
        y = h / 2;
    }else{
       ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
       ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
    }
    const scaleFontBy = fontSize / usingFontSize;  // calculates scale 
    ctx.setTransform(scaleFontBy, 0, 0, scaleFontBy, x, y);

    // render content
    ctx.fillText(text, 0, 0);      // Draw at center of transformed space

    const isRendered = ctx.getImageData(x | 0, y | 0, 1, 1).data[3];

    if(!isRendered) {console.clear(); console.error("Bad font render at size " + (usingFontSize * scaleFontBy | 0) + "px") }

    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,x, 40);

    ctx.strokeText("Font size " + (usingFontSize * scaleFontBy | 0) + "px", 0, 0);
    ctx.fillText("Font size " + (usingFontSize * scaleFontBy | 0) + "px", 0, 0);  
}



function renderLoop(time) {
    draw(text[(time / 2000 | 0) % text.length], (Math.sin(time * Math.PI / 1000 - Math.PI / 2)  * 0.5 + 0.5) ** 2 * (fontSizeMax - fontSizeMin) + fontSizeMin);
    requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);
}
```

```css
body {
   padding: 0px;
 }
 canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

### <strike>Still not fixed</strike>

<strike>If this does not solve the problem then it is likely a Chrome bug related to your system. It works for me on Win 10 32 and 64 bit systems running Chrome 75.0.3770.142</strike>

### BTW

You say

> *"I suspect this has to do with rendering time for the big emoji, ... besides the not-very robust setTimeout hack ..."*

2D rendering calls are blocking. They will not execute the next line of code until they have completed rendering. You never need to use a timeout.

Hope this helps

update

Comment: Haha best update ever :D and great code example too! However that doesn't solve the issue ... emoji still not displaying at greater font sizes on Chromium.